# A python problem in running the command to execute a python file in vs code

Tags: python

I was trying to run a python file "exe.py" on vs code by typing:

> python3 .\exe.py

But it comes with the following replys from vs code:

`python3: can't open file '/Users/exercise/my-python-app/myenv/.exe.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

No ideas why couldn't it works given that I already installed the python package and running the command in appropriate environment.

Comment: If you're in the correct directory, just run `python3 exe.py`. Backslashes are file separators only on windows, whereas you seem to be on macOS

Comment: The slash in the path is the wrong way round, making your python look for a file called `.exe.py` - `./exe.py`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact python3 is installed in your system but you are typing incorrectly the command. Imagine that you have the python file named exe.py with the following code

```
print("Hello world")
```

If you are in the same directory of the file you can execute it using the command

```
python3 exe.py
```

Another way to execute exe.py is using the shebang line. The shebang is a line that you can write to tell to the operative system which executable must use to interpret the code of the file. If you add the typical shebang for python3 in linux at the beginning of exe.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
print("Hello world")
```

and you tip the command

```
./exe.py
```

you will see the result of the execution too. If you get an error probably you have to give permissions to the file with the command

```
chmod 777 exe.py
```

You can find a lot of resources talking about the shebang. The following link talks about the shebang in python

https://www.pythonpool.com/python-shebang/

I hope you found it useful.

Greetings.

Comment: `chmod 777` is very bad advice

Comment: Indeed, with a 777 permission assignment any user on the system could read, modify and execute the script so possibly the 700 permission assignment is much more appropriate. However, I do not see any danger in assigning the 777 permissions to the script that I exposed above.

You are right that in general you have to be very careful with the permissions you assign to scripts, especially in a production environment. For example applying chmod +s permissions to the vim binary can lead to catastrophic consequences such as privilege escalation to root. More info in

https://gtfobins.github.io/

Answer (score 1):

You are running

```
python3 .\exe.py
```

which is escaping the `e` and therefore is replaced by `e` as there's no matching escape char and it becomes

```
python3 .exe.py
```

You need, as other response states

```
python3 exe.py
```

or

```
python3 ./exe.py
```